# Jabber client with support of Gtalk XEP-136

Tags: software-recommendation, jabber

I ask you to suggest any Jabber client, which support **Gtalk XEP-136** extension. This extension allows you to access the latest messages stored on the server. For example, I talk to someone through Gtalk on my phone, then open Jabber client on my computer and can see the last N (default 10) messages in the conversation.

I know only one application with this feature, and it is **Google Talk**, but it have not a native version for Ubuntu/Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Gajim**](http://gajim.org/) seems to support XEP-0136, according to [this issue](https://trac.gajim.org/ticket/3593) and the [Gajim support status for various XEPs](https://trac.gajim.org/wiki/GajimXEPSupport):

> [XEP-0136 Message Archiving](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html)
>   Support: Yes
>   Version: 1.2

You can install Gajim from *universe*: http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/precise/gajim

Comment: Even if it supports XEP 136, it doesn't load messages from server. Unfortunately, it's not, what I'm looking for, but anyway thanks for your option.

Answer (score 0):

This Google Talk feature **is not** XEP-0136, it's proprietary extension without support outside official client.